# Can't knit a html through rmarkdown

Tags: r

I'm having problems to knit an HTML in `Rmarkdown`. When I try it, using `eval = TRUE`, i got the follow error:

> ggplot(my.ret, aes(x = as.numeric(year), y = acum.ret, color = ticker)): could not find function "ggplot" Calls:  . . . handel  -> withcallinghandlers -> withvisible -> eval -> eval executed halted

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you loaded ggplot2? `library(ggplot2)`

Comment: happens this " error in eval (x, envir = envir) : argument is missing with no default calls: <Anonymous> . . .proces_group_block  -> call_block -> eval_Lang -> eval -> eval executed halted "

Comment: My hunch would be something somewhere else in the markdown isn't specified correctly but hard to tell without more context